# Merge and serialize javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to merge nested javascript object. I was simple when I the length of object was one. But since the lenght has increased I need a dynamic way to merge the `address` key and serialize my object

```
var old =  {account: "100000", address: {city: "LONDON", companyName: "Test IQUE", country: "UK", postalCode: "SW1A 2AA",}, meterName: "DM9"}
```

When lenght was 1 this worked for me

```
var new = {   
              'account' : "100000",                         
              'address' : "LONDON, UK"
              'companyName' : "Test IQUE",
              'postalCode' : "SW1A 2AA",   
              'meterName' : "DM90"
           },
           {   
              'account' : "1000001",                         
              'address' : "LONDON, UK"
              'companyName' : "Test IQUE",
              'postalCode' : "SW1A 2AA",   
              'meterName' : "DM90"
           };
```

Baiscally I need to serialize my nested `address` object and merge it into one. As the structure of each object will be same I was thinking of using a for each loop which can combine values of address into one.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn `{ city: "...", country: "...", ...}` into a string...?

Comment: Looks like you are using `angularjs`, but you are tagging javascript.

Comment: angularjs is used for adding data to object / creating new flatten object. But my question is around javascript

Comment: do you have an example of nested properties? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz editted my question to remove ambiguity

Comment: @Duck_dragon, i am still not sure, what you want ...

Comment: @NinaScholz basically I need to faltten the address nested object and merge keys inside it into one. But dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how you can get a full address string from an **addresss** object, you can use the following code:

`'address': Object.values($scope.userDetails.address).join(', ');`

The `Object.values()` function will change your `address` object into array.

The `.join` method will concatenate all of the elements from this array into one string. These elements will be separated by a string passed as an argument (`,`  in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash lib : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assignIn

@see

_.assign(object, [sources])

```
function Foo() {
    this.a = 1;
}

function Bar() {
    this.c = 3;
}

Foo.prototype.b = 2;
Bar.prototype.d = 4;

_.assign({ 'a': 0 }, new Foo, new Bar);
// => { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```

_.mergeWith(object, other, customizer);

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
    if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
        return objValue.concat(srcValue);
    }
}
 
var object = { 'a': [1], 'b': [2] };
var other = { 'a': [3], 'b': [4] };
 
_.mergeWith(object, other, customizer);
// => { 'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4] }
```